# Solutions to $\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is this an *implicit* differential equation, and how does one solve it?

$$\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}} = y^2$$

Comment: @MichaelFreimann I would have thought there was a distinction between $d^2y$ and $dy^2$

Comment: @Surb yes, I have understood it was stupid -- deleted the comment, thx

Comment: The general solution is elliptic, but for some particular choices of initial conditions the solution reduces to something simpler. For example $y(x) = \frac{6}{(x - a)^2}$ solves the equation (on any domain not containing $a$).

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\text{d}^2y(x)}{\text{d}x^2}=y(x)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y''(x)=y(x)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Multiply both sides by $y'(x)$:

---

$$y'(x)y''(x)=y'(x)y(x)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int y'(x)y''(x)\space\text{d}x=\int y'(x)y(x)^2\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

For the left integral, substitute $u=y'(x)$ and $\text{d}u=y''(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int y'(x)y''(x)\space\text{d}x=\int u\space\text{d}u=\frac{u^2}{2}+\text{C}=\frac{y'(x)^2}{2}+\text{C}$$

For the right integral, substitute $s=y(x)$ and $\text{d}s=y'(x)\space\text{d}x$:

$$\int y'(x)y(x)^2\space\text{d}x=\int u^2\space\text{d}x=\frac{u^3}{3}+\text{C}=\frac{y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}$$

---

$$\frac{y'(x)^2}{2}=\frac{y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)^2=\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+2\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Two times a constant is just another constant:

---

$$y'(x)^2=\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}}}=\pm1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}}}\space\text{d}x=\int\pm1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{\sqrt{\frac{2y(x)^3}{3}+\text{C}}}\space\text{d}x=\text{K}\pm x$$

Where $\text{C}$ and $\text{K}$ are arbitrary constants.

Comment: The solutions an elliptic function, so there's only so far one can go$\ldots$ I guess from here you can say see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions#Integral_equation).

Comment: Thanks very much. 
Is there any other way this could be done, i.e. without having to multiply both sides by y'(x)? If dy/dx is an operator, then does the answer hold?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right) &= y^2 \\
  \frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right) \times \frac{dy}{dx} &= y^2 \\
  y' \frac{dy'}{dy} &= y^2 \\
  y' \, dy' &= y^2 \, dy \\
  \frac{y'^2}{2} &= \frac{y^3}{3}+C \\
  \frac{dy}{dx} &= \sqrt{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2C} \\
  x &= \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac{2y^3}{3}+2C}} \\
    &= \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}} \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{y^3+a^3}} \\
    &= a\sqrt[4]{\frac{3}{4a^2}} \operatorname{cn}^{-1}
       \left(
         \frac{\sqrt{3}-1-\frac{y}{a}}{\sqrt{3}+1+\frac{y}{a}},
         \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}
       \right)+b \\
  y &=
  a\left[ 
     \frac{\sqrt{3}-1-(\sqrt{3}+1)
           \operatorname{cn}
           \left(
             \sqrt[4]{\frac{4}{3a^2}} \frac{x-b}{a}, \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}
           \right)}
          {1+
           \operatorname{cn}
           \left(
             \sqrt[4]{\frac{4}{3a^2}} \frac{x-b}{a}, \frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{2}}{4}
           \right)}
   \right]
\end{align*}

In particular, when $a=0$ gives

$$y=\frac{4}{(x-b)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Maple says the solution is essentially the Weierstrass $\wp$ function:
$$
y(x) = 6\wp(x+C_1;0,C_2) 
$$
See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassEllipticFunction.html
http://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/WeierstrassP/